# Guaranteeing that a worker thread keeps running

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, serial-port

My program uses a producer/consumer pattern, meaning that my producer adds tasks to a queue and my consumer executes those tasks in the background whenever there's something in the queue to execute.

My worker thread needs to use a serial port, and the standard way of using a serial port is to open it at the start of the program and keep it open for as long as it's needed (until shutdown). My program is an always-on web service, where usually objects have a lifetime scoped to the request. These two things contradict each other somewhat, so I need to make sure that when I get a request, the background thread is up and running and holding the serial port open instead of opening it for every request which might be more natural in most cases. So my program needs a high degree of self-sufficiency, it needs to detect errors in the worker thread and restart it if needed.

Is there a technique for guaranteeing that my worker thread stays up? I have considered wrapping the entire worker thread's code in a try/catch, and sending an event to the main thread in the finally block so that the worker can be restarted. Or I could continually send "ping" events to the main thread to let it know that the worker thread is still running, or even poll the worker thread from the main thread.

Is there a standard way of doing this? What's the most robust approach? Note that it's fine if the worker thread dies or becomes unable to complete its work for whatever reason - I will just restart the thread and keep trying, however ideally if that happens it should be able to put its task back in the queue.

Examples in C#/F#/dotnet (framework) are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The best approach might be to run a separate process (Win NT Service). After that, Asp.Net Core has much better support for running a background process.

Comment: That's a good point, and one I hadn't considered. It does make a few things like deployment and updates significantly more complicated though (I expect to support 100+ installations). I've also experienced that windows services do not automatically restart themselves sometimes when they are closed, which would be a problem. I would still have to manually guarantee that the services is up. It's an attractive solution because I could indeed use :NET core then, for most of my services. But my main question would still stand - how do I guarantee the uptime of these services?

Comment: NT services can be set to restart (until manually shut down). For the rest, it depends on lots of factors. But be aware that there is no 'main thread' in ASP.NET.